# Why the feature to insert date/time not work in gedit?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, gedit

When I tried to insert the date/time of gedit, no data was inserted into the document. Only blank spaces appeared in the current cursor position. 
I tried again from the terminal, it was the same and no error message.

Any hints to identify the error or if there is something wrong in the settings?

Additional Information: gedit version 3.2.1-0ubuntu2 - 11.10 - 64-bit

Comment: This is a bug, and it is a confirmed issue (see accepted answer). As such, this is too localized. I'll vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a confirmed issue [LP Bug# 886785](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/886785) and is being worked on.

Comment: Thanks, I think soon in a small update this detail will be right.

Answer (score 2):

Try this work around. Look in *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Insert Time and Date* > *Preferences*.

Select the **Prompt for a format** radio button. Close and Close again.

Now when you *Edit* > *Insert Time and Date* you should now be asked for a format from the drop down list. Select and enter.

Works for me on my ACER laptop.

Comment: Thanks! I think there is some issue as seen LP Bug # 886785, but after using the preferences sometimes seems to work partially.